# How do i get which element is clicked/focused in blur event of another element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react application, I have blur event listener, in my listener function I want to know, on which the focus went to. How can I get to know that in chrome browser?

The below is my onBlur event function

```
const handleBlurOfDateInput = (date, event) => {
    const valueEntered = datetoMomentDate(date);
    // Here i want to check, which element got focused using event
    hide && hide();
    onChange(valueEntered);
};
```

Comment: Could you, please, restate your question? It's hard to understand what exactly is your problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.target`, or `document.getElementFromPoint(event.pageX, event.pageY)`

```
const handleBlurOfDateInput = (date, event) => {
    const valueEntered = datetoMomentDate(date);
    // Here i want to check, which element got focused using event
    hide && hide();
    onChange(valueEntered);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleBlurOfDateInput = (date, event) => {
  const valueEntered = datetoMomentDate(date);
  if(event.relatedTarget){console.log(event.relatedTarget)}
  hide && hide();
  onChange(valueEntered);
};
```

You can use [relatedTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent/relatedTarget).

Notice that relatedTarget will return null if the element focused is not an input. In this case, you can use tabIndex = '0' for that element.

Comment: Hi @fjplaurr - what do you mean by `using tabIndex = '0'`? Not quite sure how to implement that in place of `event.relatedTarget`. Thanks